# EF4.3 dependency injection when creating new objects yourself

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject, dbcontext

I'm building an MVC3 application using the Entity Framework. In the application my controllers talk to a service layer. One of the controllers is a `TournamentController` which uses the `TournamentService`. This service has some standard methods such as `CreateTournament`, `UpdateTournament` etc.

When I want to insert a new tournament I want the view to have a dropdownlist of possible sports for which the tournament can be organised. So in the `TournamentController's` `Create` method I fill the `ViewBag.Sports` with a list of possible sports. Now to obtain this list of sports I use `_tournamentService.GetAllSports()`. In this `GetAllSports()` method of the `TournamentService` I want to create an instance of the `SportService` so I can 'forward' the question to the right service.

All services use dependency injection in the constructor to inject their own repository, like so:

```
private ITournamentRepository _repo;

public TournamentService(ITournamentRepository repo) {
    _repo = repo;
}
```

My `GetAllSports()` method in the `TournamentService` looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Sport> GetAllSports() {
    ISportService sportService = new SportService();
    return sportService.GetSports();
}
```

The problem is that by calling the `new SportService()` it expects me to hand it an `ISportRepository` like in the `TournamentService`, where ninject creates the `TournamentRepository`. Now I could do the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Sport> GetAllSports() {
    ISportService sportService = new SportService(new SportRepository());
    return sportService.GetSports();
}
```

But the problem with that is that each repository expects an IContext, which is normally handled by ninject as well. Furthermore, I don't want two separate contexts to be instantiated.

A possible solution I found myself is to do this:

```
private ITournamentRepository _repo;
private ISportService _sportService;

public TournamentService(ITournamentRepository repo, ISportService sportService) {
    _repo = repo;
    _sportService = sportService
}
```

But there's only one method in my `TournamentService` class that would actually use the `_sportService` so I figure this is a bit overkill to make it a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, inject `ISportService` to your controller and call `sportService.GetSports()` directly from the controller!

Comment: Well that's what I originally had, but I felt that having two services in one controller was less clean than having one service call another. As I'm only just starting to use these service layers and repositories I'm not sure if it's just a personal feeling or a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your last solution valid. Inject the necessary service as part of the constructor.

And if you're worried about multiple contexts, don't let two separate contexts be created then.

In your Ninject binding:

```
Bind<ITournamentRepository>().To<TournamentRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

See https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope

The last piece is the important part. It will only create one instance of TournamentRepository for the current request. Any other requesters of TournamentRepository will get this instance.

If you're already doing this, you're set, otherwise, just add InRequestScope and you're done. (keeping in mind you'll need a reference to Ninject.Web.Common)

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

Remo is correct, I wouldn't call this from a service either. Just call for your lookup data from the controller and populate your view model. The InRequestScope advice still holds.

Comment: Thank you for the `InRequestScope` advice, I had incorrectly assumed that ninject would automatically do this.